# Navigating to pop-up without a mouse

Tags: keyboard, xcode, accessibility

[image: Xcode screenshot showing pop-up]

(By way of background I have been helping a local blind child learn coding. He's switching schools from a Windows based school to a Mac based school so I am trying to familiarise myself with VoiceOver on the Mac.)

When using VoiceOver and Xcode to write Swift into a new Swift Playground a pop-up window appeared requesting my password.

How might I navigate to the pop-up without using a mouse?

I tried the arrow keys, tab, with and without ⌘, and ⌘ `, all to no avail.

(N.B. Unless I could see the screen I would have had no idea that the pop-up had appeared, VoiceOver did not mention it.)

Comment: I've cross-posted [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250604727) too, I hope that's OK.

Comment: See keyboard -> Shortcuts -> full screen access.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii do you mean "full screen access"? I can see "full keyboard access" [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204434)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I tried tab, but the pop-up did not have focus so tab just prints a tab in the Swift Playground